# Timeseries forecasting (Load forecasting) - Apparent shift in actual vs predicted values when applying regression model

Tags: regression, forecasting, predictive-models, scikit-learn, feature-engineering

Tools/languages/techniques I am using

- python
- scikit-learn
- different regression models (only linear regression is shown here for simplicity)

I am working on a regression problem. The data I have is time-series hourly consumption data and I am trying to make a step-ahead prediction.

I first prepared the data and made sure no data from the future is spilled into the training data. So for consumption at a certain hour (h0), the record will look as follows

| feature1 | feature2 | target |
| --- | --- | --- |
| h-2 | h-1 | h0 |

Where **h-1** and **h-2** are the previous two hours.

#### Note

> I am adding two hours here for simplicity. However, in reality, I am
> using different lag values and moving averages as features.

I trained the model and then applied the predict function to test data.

After that, I plotted the actual vs prediction (*y_test* vs *y_predict*), but it seems that there is some shift where the prediction is shifted by one hour in the future as you can see below

[image]

I tried to shift the prediction back by one hour the performance difference was huge

> R2 **increased** from 0.64 to 0.89 (**39%** enhancement)

> RMSE **dropped** from 1003 to 536.8 (**46.5%** enhancement)

##### My Question

- What could I be doing wrong?
- Am I doing something wrong or could this shift be an indication of something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shift is an indication of a very strong correlation with the previous lag `h-1` and a low correlation with other feature variables.

In other words, the model is mainly using `h-1` to estimate the current hour consumption `h`.

While this can lead to acceptable results (and sometimes really good results as well) in terms of `R2` and `RMSE`. It also means that the model is not really better than a baseline model that just uses `h-1` to estimate `h` (i.e. `f(h) = h-1`)

In this case, a machine learning model is just adding complexity with no clear improvement in performance. ***Nothing smart going on here***

This [video](https://youtu.be/FYyhBeZZN-U?t=944) from Marco Peixeiro, the author of the book ***Time Series Forecasting in Python*** discusses this exact problem as well